# wordpress webstie restriction or blocking, only registred users can view the website

Tags: wordpress, web, blocking

I am creating a website on top wordpress,

The reason to use wordpress is that,
We want to restrict or block the entire site,
Only registered people should be able to access the site that too after verification,

Can anybody help me choosing the right plugins to achieve this.

Note : the site will be similar to a membership website, but the users who are going to use this are not paying, We just want to allow only people whom we approve.

Example: The steps are the one we are looking,

1. Default page should be Registration page,
2. Once Registered, Email verification has to be done by clicking the link in the Email ID giving during registration,
3. Post verification, Email with log-in page link along with username & password goes to the user's registered Email ID,
4. User logs-in using the username and password,
5. User is able to view the entire site

I AM A NEWBIE IN WORDPRESS,

Thanks
Ashok

Answer (score 0):

Check this plugin : https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-user-frontend/

It's the best to make membership / private page / registration page and etc.. and he is the most documented plugin on this.

Have fun and welcome on Wordpress :)